# Bot Framework Skills - Debug without Authentication

Tags: botframework

I'm locally testing integration between a bot and a skill by starting both projects and connect with the emulator to the parent bot. But unfortunately, it only works when I configure the parent bot and skill to have have the credentials (app id + password) set, as well in the emulator.
It would make things quicker to test unauthenticated.
Any idea how to workaround that?

Comment: Don't provide AppId and Password while connecting to the bot. Also in your Project > appSettings.json file make sure the MicrosoftAppId and MicrosoftAppPassword both are blank.

Comment: @noobprogrammer This works to test a single bot, but it doesn't 
work like this for a bit to skill connection.

Answer (score 0):

As the framework is currently, using skills without AppId/Password in emulator isn't. This is because the the authentication logic is tightly woven in communication between consumer bot and skill bot, unfortunately.
Good news is that is on the SDK team's radar.

**See GitHub issue here for its tracking:
https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-sdk/issues/5726**

It is currently scheduled to release during Bot Framework R11 (current milestone), releasing end of October. It is possible however, depending on how complicated the improvement will be, that the feature might be pushed to the next milestone, R12.